# sql query to apply min-max normalization to different columns in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, normalization

I have different columns containing int values like age, gender etc. I want these column values to be replaced with 0-1 range values by applying min-max normalization so that i can load it to rapid minor and apply k-means.

plz tell me the sql query of this?

Comment: Well, you could add your table structure and some sample data...

Answer (score 6):

The query to calculate this is as follows

```
SELECT
    1.00*(Age-MinAge)/AgeRange,
    1.00*(Gender-MinGender)/GenderRange,
FROM
    (
    SELECT
       Age,
       MIN(Age) OVER () AS MinAge,
       MAX(Age) OVER () - MIN(Age) OVER () AS AgeRange,
       Gender,
       MIN(Gender) OVER () AS MinGender,
       MAX(Gender) OVER () - MIN(Gender) OVER () AS GenderRange,
    FROM
       MyTable
    ) X
```

You can use this to populate a new table or new columns etc

Comment: What's X over here?

Comment: X is a required alias of the derived table. Remove "X" and see what happens